# Should I catch exceptions without meaningful recovery?

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling

I am trying to read a file:

`void read_file(std::string_view file_name);`

The definition of this function is not important, however this function may throw (file may not exist, file may be corrupted, etc.).

Successful file read is very crucial to my program, but I **don't** want to do any meaningful recovery (trying different file, etc.) when this function throws.

What should I do?

a). when it throws, then do nothing, and program terminates with e.g. `std::runtime()` error's message

b). catch it, and inside catch print `what()`, and terminate program with `std::exit()`

So option **b).** produces kind of similiar output behaviour to option **a).**, but option **b).** needs to introduce `try/catch` keywords "bloat".

Is option **b).** a normal practice or bad? Which one should I use?

Comment: it is up to you to decide what you want. Sometimes diagnostics in case of termination are not needed, often they are....

Comment: The choice basically depends on the level of comfort you want to provide to your program users. Normal people usually don't like _unhandled exception_ messages ;-).

Comment: fwiw, for fatal exceptions (ones that you know for sure that you cannot recover from) I agree with the answer, but you also have "file does not exist" on your list, which imho should not lead to termination in the first place. Consider to ask the user to select a different file, or reenter the correct file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, no.

Many people I 've seen do a `try/catch` on errors like `std::bad_alloc`, only to realize that they just can't do anything apart from a clean exit. When `new[]` fails, either the OS is very unstable or (99,999%) the program has a bug that has to be fixed.

Most times you only need a top level exception handler that can:

- Save a crash dump,
- Release any resources that have to be released for a reason before app termination (most probably none)
- Attempt a recovery if the crash occurs in a thread that can be terminated and/or restarted, so the main thread and the app continues to run. Even if it's the main thread you may try a dirty (but sometimes working) `longjmp` recovery.
- Save a recovery file/project/document
- Exit and notify the user

When you have a library function that would throw an exception when the file is not found then there's an error in the design. Exception handling should be there for *exceptions*, which are generally unrecoverable errors at the CPU level (such as bad pointer access), not for common errors like fnf, invalid password etc. A function that reads a file should simply return an error if the file is not found, not throw an exception. If you are stuck with such a function then you have to use try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

`main' should always catch exceptions. At the very least, the program can describe what went wrong. If it doesn't catch the exception, it's up to the compiler vendor to decide what, if anything, to report. Do your users a favor and produce a coherent and consistent error message.

In addition, if the program doesn't catch the exception, it is not guaranteed that destructors for objects on the call stack will be called. That could result in abandoned resources or other nasty things. And it's up to the implementation to decide whether to do that. Don't leave that to chance. Catch the exception.